# Opening Instance of Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, out-of-memory

I have an app that hold post information in an activity. in this activity related posts listed in bottom of post. User by clicking on related post can go to post activity and see that post info and related posts too.

[image: Figure]

As you can see in image, I have **Activity A** that holds post and it's related posts. When user Click on post I send user to **Activity A with new post id** and fill activity by new data.

But I think this is not Right way!

should I used `Fragment` instead of `Activity`?

Comment: If I were you I use fragment. because usually details page repeated in different part of Application so this improve reusability of your code.

Comment: @Amir Yep! whats I'm considering now, is to create an activity called it `PostActivity` that hold `PostFragment` and then create an Interface to do fragment replacing for activity.. What's you idea about it?

Comment: Yeah that's good way. But I don't get it why you need interface?

Comment: @Amir Well, I don't want send user to activity when clicked on related item, I just want to say activity to replace this fragment with new instance of this with new data and save it in back stack.

Comment: May isn't necessary to do this, see this code from googler :https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: @Amir This sample, Send user from `CheeseListFragment` to `CheeseDetailsActivity`, right? but if you want to got to anoder cheese!! should press back and see List fragment! but in my app I have list of details (cheese! :D) in Details Activity! and should send user to DetailsActivity again!! got it? ;)

Comment: Yeah, in this scenario using activity is better I think

Comment: This is the EXACT reason why fragments exist. I'll quote some sections from the Android Fragments developer guide.

`"A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity."` & `"You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, ... (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities)."` & `"You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity component."`

Answer (score 1):

Opening another Instance of an Activity on top of another is simplest way of navigating a content graph. User can simply press back, and go to previously opened content, until user reaches back to starting Activity, then the application closes. Though pretty straight forward, this particular approach has two issues:

1. It may happen that a lot of Instances of same activity are on the stack, utilising a large amount of device resources like memory.
2. You don't have a fine grained control over Activity Stack. You can only launch more activities, finish some, or have to resort to intent flags like `FLAG_CLEAR_TOP` etc.

There is another approach, that re-uses the same Activity instance, loads new content in it while also remembering the history of content that was loaded. Much like a web browser does with web page urls.

The Idea is to keep a `Stack` of content viewed so far. Loading new content pushes more data to stack, while going back pops the top content from stack, until it is empty. The Activity UI always displays the content from top of the stack.

Rough Example:

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // keep history of viewed posts, with current post at top
    private final Stack<Post> navStack = new Stack<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // get starting link from intent extras and call loadPost(link) 
    }

    private void loadPost(String link){
        // Load post data in background and then call onPostLoaded(post)
        // this is also called when user clicks on a related post link 
    }

    private void onPostLoaded(Post post){
        // add new post to stack
        navStack.push(post);

        // refresh UI
        updateDisplay();
    }

    private void updateDisplay(){

        // take the top Post, without removing it from stack
        final Post post = navStack.peek();

        // Display this post data in UI
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // pop the top item
        navStack.pop();

        if(navStack.isEmpty()) {
            // no more items in history, should finish
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else {
            // refresh UI with the item that is now on top of stack
            updateDisplay();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // cancel any background post load, release resources
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## I would choose:

activity/fragment depends on complexity  with:

- horizontal recyclerview with custom expanded card view
- and inside this expanded card view second vertical recyclerview :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try.

Create a `PostActivity` which is a shell for fragments. Inside this activity you can just replace fragments using `FragmentTransaction`.

Your `PostActivity` can now have a `PostFragment` which will hold post and related posts. Now on click of post you can replace `PostFragment` with `PostDetailFragment` with `postID` being sent to the new fragment as a bundle. The `PostDetailFragment` will now display details according to id.

Check here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html#components_fragments

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the picture the way i would implement is i would have create an activity with a bottom listview for your items and on top there would be a framelayout for holding fragments . when user click on any list item i would load the respective fragment in the activity

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. What would you expect to happen when the user touches the back button after going down a couple of levels? If you want to the application to exit, no matter how deep in the sequence they have gone, then the best solution in my opinion is to simply reload the same activity with the new data and invaliding the affected views. If you need the back button to take the user back to the previous data, then the next question would be if you are keeping track of the past data breadcrumb. If so, then just intercept the back button and load the previous data for as long as there is data in your stack, or exit if you get to the top. If you don't want to keep track of the previous data chain, then instead of loading one activity with the new data, you can start a new activity of the same class, but with the new data. Android with keep the track of activities and each back button touch would close the running activity and take the user to the previous activity. Choice of activity versus fragment is just yours. You can use fragments that hold the data that you want to change after each user touch, create new ones when needed, disconnect the previous ones, and connect the new ones. You will need to do some extra work to make sure the back button works correctly (depending on you want the back button to behave). Based on what I can tell, it is simpler to just have one activity and load new data when needed and keep a trail of data changes, if you need to be able to go back.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using activity alone. Though I preferred moving all related UI to fragment.

You can use Navigator class.

Here the steps:
 **1. Add Navigator Class**

```
public class Navigator {

  private static Navigator instance;

  public synchronized static Navigator getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Navigator();
    }
    return instance;
  }

   public void navigateToActivityA(Context context) {
      Intent activity= AActivity.getCallingIntent(context);
      context.startActivity(activity);
  }
}
```

**2. Add the calling method to your Activity class.**

```
public static Intent getCallingIntent(Context context) {
return new Intent(context, AActivity.class);
}
```

**3. Call the activity with the following code in your caller activity.**

```
Navigator.getInstance().navigateToActivityA(this);
```

I suggest that you read about [AndroidCleanArchitecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture)

Answer (score 0):

For this task...

**0) Starting new activity**

I read again about question, and understood that you need advice for starting activity. So, starting new activity it's Ok, your main problem will be with another things (see below).

But lets talk about starting another data. Using Fragment instead doesn't resolve your task, fragments helps with different screen work. Using for example just data refreshing as a variant. You may use just single activity and refresh only data, it will look much better, if you also add animation, but not better than starting activity.

Using Fragment helps your with different screen actions. And maybe, answering on your question - it will be **most suitable solution**. You just use single acitivity - PostActivity, and several fragments - FragmentMainPost, FragmentRelated - which will be replaced, each other, by selecting from related post.

**1) Issues with returning back**

Lets imagine, that users clicks to new one activity and we loaded new data. It's Ok, and when Users clicks over 100 activities and receiving a lot of information. It's Ok, too. But main question here it's returning back (also another about caching, but lets leave it, for now).

So everyone know, it's bad idea to save a lot of activities in stack. So for my every application, with similar behavior we override onBackPressed in this activity. But how, lets see the flow below:

```
//Activities most have some unique ID for saving, for ex, post number. 
//Users clicks to 100 new activities, just start as new activity, and
//finish previous, via method, or setting parameter for activity in AndroidManifest 
<activity
   noHistory=true>
</activity>

 ....

//When activity loaded, save it's activity data, for ex, number of post 
//in some special place, for example to our Application. So as a result 
//we load new activity and save information about it to list
 ....

// User now want return back. We don't save all stack this activities, 
// so all is Ok. When User pressing back, we start action for loading 
//activities,  saved on our list..

.....

   onBackPressed () {
      //Getting unique list
       LinkedTreeSet<PostID> postList =    
            getMyApplication().getListOfHistory();

      //Getting previous Post ID based on current
      PostID previousPostID = postList.get(getCurrentPost());

      //Start new activity with parameter (just for ex)
      startActivity(new Intent().putExtra(previousPostID));

   }
```

**RESULT**

I found this as the best solution for this tasks. Because in every time - we work only with single activity!